# web server returns segfault when reloading webpage constantly + other error

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm making a C web server on my raspberry pi and I've come across a problem where when I constantly reload the webpage, the web server gives me a segmentation fault. It also sometimes refuses to run the threads after a while of constant traffic. I used gdb to debug the segfault and this is what I found:

```
Thread 145 "webServer" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x6f59b440 (LWP 21885)]
memcpy () at ../sysdeps/arm/memcpy.S:196
196 ../sysdeps/arm/memcpy.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/arm/memcpy.S:196
#1  0xb6e94b48 in __GI__IO_file_xsgetn (fp=0x52719f08, data=<optimized out>, 
    n=1) at fileops.c:1303
#2  0xb6e87df8 in __GI__IO_fread (buf=0x2343c <fileLine>, size=1, count=1, 
    fp=0x52719f08) at iofread.c:38
#3  0x000114c4 in handleClient (pClientSock=0x23830 <clientSock>)
    at webServer.c:242
#4  0x000116a0 in giveThreadWork () at webServer.c:298
#5  0xb6f7f494 in start_thread (arg=0x6f59b440) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0xb6f02568 in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/clone.S:73
   from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I couldn't find anything for the refusing threads though.

It says that there are some problems on lines: 242 and 298. All there is there, is the following:

```
Line 242-266
============

    while ((freadErr = fread(fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), 1, fpointer)) != 0) {
        if (freadErr < 0) {
            printf("fread error\n");
            perror("fread");
            close(acceptSock);
            memset_all();
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((send(acceptSock, httpResponse, strlen(httpResponse), MSG_NOSIGNAL)) == -1) {
            printf("write error1\n");
            perror("we1");
            close(acceptSock);
            memset_all();
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((send(acceptSock, fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), MSG_NOSIGNAL)) == -1) {
            printf("write error2\n");
            perror("we2");
            close(acceptSock);
            memset_all();
            return NULL;
        }
        memset(fileLine, 0, 1);
        memset(httpResponse, 0, 1000);




line 285-304 (298 is where error is)
==================

void *giveThreadWork() {
    while (1) {
        int *pclient;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if ((pclient = dequeue()) == NULL) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition_var, &mutex);
            pclient = dequeue();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if (pclient != NULL) {
            handleClient(pclient);
        } else {
            printf("\n\n\n\n\n no more listener \n\n\n\n\n");
            close(*pclient);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get anymore info from gdb but maybe someone else knows how. I've tried changing the strcpy() functions and checked all the string manipulation functions (or i'm pretty sure I have) and I've found nothing.

Here is all the code if anyone needs it: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/xokipuvidu.c

Hopefully someone can help or point me in the right direction

Comment: One thing that looks wrong is that the threaded code is using unprotected global variables such as `fpointer`. That means there is a good chance that any thread will corrupt the value for other threads.

Comment: @kaylum, do you think that could be the cause of the threads refusing to run?

Comment: Quite possible. Though the exact behaviour is unpredictable. But it's certainly a major bug and must be fixed before continuing. There's really no reason why those variables even need to be global in the first place.

Comment: @kaylum, so how would I protect the fpointer? Would I put a mutex lock around it while its being used?

Comment: regarding: `freadErr = fread(fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), 1, fpointer)) != 0) {
        if (freadErr < 0) {`  here is what the Man page says about the returned value? *On  success,  fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items read or
       written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only  when
       size  is 1.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the
       return value is a short item count (or zero).*  so it never returns a value < 0

Comment: regarding: `printf("write error2\n");
            perror("we2");`  the function `printf()` can change the value of `errno` so the call to `perror()` should be before the call to `printf()`